# Python/Django: The view xxxxx didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I have this view:

```
def do_some_work(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.FILES['some_file']

        I do some work in the file

        dates_people= [list of things]
        maestros = {dict of things}
        talks_count= [same here]

        return render(request, 'wappApp/work.html', context={'dates': dates_people, 'maestros': solo_users,'talks': talks_count})
```

This view is called from a button click in the template

```
<form  action="{% url "do_some_work" %}" method="POST"     enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="some_file">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

what i am getting is, after selecting the file and clicking submit, is a browser page saying: 'This webpage is not available' and after refreshing the page i get the:

```
The view App.views.calculation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I tried to debug this view but  can not reach it.

This is the url for this view:

```
url(r'^work/$', views.calculation, name='do_some_work'),
```

Any idea what is going on?. Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I don't know why is returning a NONE object if my form has a POST method and is pointig in the 'action' to my view

Thanks

** 2nd EDIT**

I marked as correct the only answer just because i realized that i needed to handle the Not POST requests.

I keep getting the none object because i do not know why the form is using a GET method

**EDIT 3**

AS recommended by @BriceP i added the {% csrf_token %} tag to my template. Now the POST method is working.

But apparently the file that i am uploading (.txt file) is not behaving as it is spected.

[image: Debugging the method]

When i reach this line "lines = data.split" i get this error:

```
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'split'
```

But if the community has a problem with me asking more things i will write another question.

Thanks

Comment: 1) `do_some_work` view in your url - where is it from? Should it be `calculation` instead? 2) render shorcut function requires template_name argument.

Comment: Sorry @chem1st yes you are right, i changed what you mentioned but still having the same problem

Comment: Once again, where is your `do_some_work` view? You get a HttpResponse error, cause there is no data sent by post after refreshing.

Comment: @chem1st yes i changed it, sorry. what i am doing is sending a file, the 'calculation' view has to recibe that file, but that is not happening.

Comment: If your request is not a POST request, the view will return `None`. You need to make sure that the view always returns and HttpResponse object or throw an exception.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.. you need to post more context.

Comment: @ArnarYngvason i edited my question, but basically what i con not understand is why my form is not sending a POST request. I am lost.

Comment: 'This webpage is not available' error is hardly occured because of your response is None. As I've already said, you get HttpResponse error after refreshing. There is simply no data posted, and so your `if` statement is not working. Try to debug your view with `print` or by commenting some of `calculation` view code out.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `csrf` tag, as I wrote in the update of my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this at the end of calculation() :

```
return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

or redirect to the form page :

```
return redirect('your-form-view')
```

Then, if you call the page, you'll either enter the `if` and have your data managed, or raise your exception or have your redirection.

Without this, if your `if` doesn't validate, the default behaviour is returning `None`, which for some reason seems to be occuring to you.

EDIT : 
Also, your form is missing `{% csrf_token %}`. But I don't know why you're not seeing a CSRF validation error. Maybe you're developping without `debug = True`? Anyway, a view should always return an http response, or redirect to another page, so even if none of this is your answer, you should manage the case where the method is GET.

Comment: 404 is the wrong status to be sending for this. It should be a `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: You're right, Amar. I edited my answer with HttpResponseNotAllowed. Thanks!